# Display Range of Date in Specific Month

Tags: php

I want to display date range for specific month in php as shown below:

Suppose i select month January and year 2015 then code should display :

```
Date 01/01/2015 to 10/01/2015
     10/01/2015 to 20/01/2015
     21/01/2015 to 31/01/2015
```

Kindly help me out to resolve this issue as soon as possible.
thanks in advance..

Comment: i tried but it shows me all the dates in month but i want to display specific range as shown above . Kindly help me. please.

Comment: I didn't ask IF, but WHAT. This site is not for solving your tasks for you, but helping on the base of what have you tried, if you got stuck. Without any code, nobody will answer you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
          $list=array();
          $month = 11;
          $year = 2014;

      for($d=1; $d<=31; $d++)
      {
         $time=mktime(12, 0, 0, $month, $d, $year);          
        if (date('m', $time)==$month)       
         $list[]=date('Y-m-d-D', $time);
      }
         echo "<pre>";
       print_r($list);

       echo "</br>";
       echo $list[0] . "  to  " . $list[9] ."</br>";

      echo $list[10]. "  to  " .$list[19]  ."</br>";

      echo $list[20]. "  to  " . end($list) ."</br>";

     echo "</pre>";
```

output

```
     2014-11-01-Sat  to  2014-11-10-Mon 
     2014-11-11-Tue  to  2014-11-20-Thu 
     2014-11-21-Fri  to  2014-11-30-Sun
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function dateRange( $first, $last, $step = '+10 days', $format = 'Y/m/d' ) {

    $dates = array();
    $current = strtotime( $first );
    $last = strtotime( $last );

    while( $current <= $last ) {

        $dates[] = date( $format, $current );
        $current = strtotime( $step, $current );
    }

    return $dates;
}


$dates = dateRange( '2010/07/26', '2010/08/05') ;
foreach($dates as $date)
{
    echo $date;

}
```

Comment: thanks. but it shows me Array ( [0] => 2010/07/26 [1] => 2010/08/05 ). how can i convert in string ?